# Which skill would best befit a farmer background: survival or nature? Or would a tool like herbalist fit better?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

I'm trying to craft a character who's background and personality is rooted (pun intended) in the no-nonsense, earthy (there it is again!) understanding of the world. Farmer Maggot from LOTR is kind of the inspiration for this character.

Nature feels too bookish, and Survival reads as more wilderness than field. Herbalist seems too narrow.

I'm looking for opinions on character crafting that are informed by the way the skills or tools are designed. I only want to invest one skill for this role play flavor.

Comment: Your question isn't actually answerable in its current state. The "best" skill for a farmer is very opinion-based, and we avoid opinion-based answers here. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: What is your character's background?

Comment: Opinion questions don't fit well in this format. Try to find a way to ask your questions which can be backed up with facts/quotes from the book or at least professional experience. As is, you literally state that you are looking for opinions.

Comment: One thing that you can do to focus your question is to think about what a farmer should know in your world. How much he knows about wildlife, how about hunting? What other things, aside from farming, does he do? If you narrow it to a point which we can compare the different skills and say, well, this fit most the description because -skill- focus on -this-, -this, and -this, and your farmer does -that-, -that-, and -that-.

Comment: It was a non-rule and opinion question. I probably should have done Reddit or something, but I like y'all better. The comments have given me the direction I need, though. I'll fluff a background with the herbalist kit; and survival can help me mechanically play some farming stuff ('cause a country boy can survive, right?). That'll help me roleplay farming some. Thanks for your patience and comments. How do I close this question? Or is that done?